# install python-kerberos on windows

Tags: python, windows, kerberos

I'm trying to install kerberos on windows, I download Zip package and in Kerberos folder I run this command : python setup.py install but I got this error :

```
error: command 'C:\\Users\\aicha\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\
\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Thks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution may be found here: [Python Kerberos-1.1.1.tar.gz Install Failure on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345000/python-kerberos-1-1-1-tar-gz-install-failure-on-windows)

Basically, python kerberos is not supported on Windows, so you will have to use kerberos-sspi instead.