# tcms-api 5.3 package incompatible with Windows

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I attempted to upgrade my tcms-api library from 5.0 to 5.3 using:

```
pip install tcms-api --upgrade
```

on a Windows 10 machine, I saw a lot of errors when trying to install the dependent package of kerberos. Even though [this is old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345000/python-kerberos-1-1-1-tar-gz-install-failure-on-windows), I saw a similar set of errors. The package installation failed since the kerberos package isn't supported on Windows and I was left at tcms-api 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I was able to do the following (caveat: I haven't extensively tested my installation yet):

- Clone the tcms-api repo from GitHub
- Edit setup.py to change the install_requires line to use 'kerberos-sspi' rather than 'kerberos'
- Install the following pip packages: Setuptools, Wheel, Twine
- CD to repo folder and run: python setup.py bdist_wheel
- That creates a package under the dist folder
- Run pip install dist\tcms_api-5.3-py3-none-any.whl
- Celebrate successful package install

The steps were modified from [this page](https://dzone.com/articles/executable-package-pip-install).

**Update:**
I confirmed the things I need the API to do work with my custom package (create and update test runs). However, I'm in a situation where I don't need to specifically harden my Kiwi instance using kerberos authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Please file a bug against https://github.com/kiwitcms/tcms-api.

We can do a quick fix by providing 2 package names:
`tcms-api` and `tcms-api[kerberos]`

The first one will not install the kerberos package.

The proposed workaround makes sense but changing the underlying kerberos implementation needs careful testing which isn't a quick job.

OTOH https://github.com/kiwitcms/python-social-auth-kerberos uses `gssapi` which seems to be the latest and most actively maintained implementation of Kerberos for Python. There is an open issue to migrate to that in tcms-api so you can contribute if you want.

Comment: [Issue](https://github.com/kiwitcms/tcms-api/issues/3) opened. Thanks for the response!